# Open GL ES Retina Display Setup

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, retina-display

I am trying to get an OpenGL project rendering correctly to a iphone retina display and I seem to be running into some difficulty. I have set the content scale factor to the devices but now the framebuffer is failing to be created.

This is all done in a subclass of EAGLView int the createFramebuffer method.

Here is my setup:

glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &viewFramebuffer);
    glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &viewRenderbuffer);

```
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);

self.contentScaleFactor = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
[context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES fromDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer*)self.layer];
glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);


glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth);
glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &backingHeight);//Depth
glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &depthRenderbuffer);
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, depthRenderbuffer);
glRenderbufferStorageOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES, backingWidth, backingHeight);
glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, depthRenderbuffer);


glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);



NSLog(@"scale Factor: %f",self.contentScaleFactor);
```

The scale factor is reported correctly but the display will not render and the buffer fails to be created. Am I missing something here?

Comment: What values do backingWidth and backingHeight have at the end of this? Are those correct for the pixel size of the view? Are you checking the status of the framebuffer via `glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER)` or another means?

Comment: The checking the values I get: scale Factor: 2.000000 backingWidth:640 backingHeight:960. These are the correct sizes for my display. And glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) does not return GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES.

Comment: @jcb344 I'm experiencing a similar problem, did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run into the same problem. You just have to multiply the frame size with the screen scale as I have stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19183188/1130270) answer.